# custom transition animation "stack cards"

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

i'd like to create a custom animation, in which cards are stacked on a deck. The new view will be the topmost card. The cards are supposed to fall down, and it works fine with one card. The difficulty is to make more than one card falling down. So far, this is what my code looks like:

```
 func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning){
    let container = transitionContext.containerView()
    let fromView  = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)
    let toViewContoller = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey) as LWCBigCardRootViewController
    let numberOfCards = toViewContoller.currentCardDeck.questions.count

    let offScreen = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)

    toViewContoller.view.alpha = 0
    toViewContoller.view.transform = offScreen

    container.addSubview(fromView!)
    container.addSubview(toViewContoller.view) 
    let duration = transitionDuration(transitionContext)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(transitionDuration(transitionContext), animations: {
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfCards; i++){
            UIView.animateWithDuration(self.transitionDuration(transitionContext), animations: {
                toViewContoller.view.alpha = 1
                toViewContoller.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                }, completion: {(ok) in
                    toViewContoller.view.alpha = 0
                    toViewContoller.view.transform = offScreen
                })
            }
        toViewContoller.view.alpha = 1
        toViewContoller.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    },
        completion: {(finished) in transitionContext.completeTransition(true)})
}
```

my goal is to duplicate the falling down animation of the view to make it look like there are several cards falling down. Right now, this results in a black screen.

Comment: You are just repeatedly saying to animate one and the same thing (`toViewController.view`). You do not have "several cards" in the plural. You have just one "card", and then you are nonsensically saying to animate it multiple times _simultaneously_. This merely kills the animation, because you have multiple conflicting animations on the same object.

Comment: To work out your animation, forget about the transition and just think about how to make this animation within a normal view. Get the details worked out. Then come back and think about how to create the same effect during a transition.

Comment: the word simultaneously brought me to the right path. I had to learn about animation chaining in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Excellent. I thought that would do it. I'm glad to hear that you worked this out.

Comment: Do not modify your question to include the answer! If you want me to give any of my above comments as an answer, just tell me. Alternatively, provide your own answer (and accept it 48 hours later). Either approach is fine; asking your own question and answering it is perfectly good Stack Overflow etiquette. Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

**possible Solution**

Maybe not the cleanest of all ways, but this works for me:

```
func startCardStacking(context: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning, numberOfCards: Int){
    cards = numberOfCards
    cards--

    var plainCard = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"Card"))
    plainCard.frame = toViewController.view.frame

    let offScreen = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
    plainCard.alpha = 0
    plainCard.transform = offScreen
    container.addSubview(plainCard)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(transitionDuration(context), animations: {
        plainCard.alpha = 1
        plainCard.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        }, completion: {(lastOne) in if(self.cards == 0){
            self.stackLastCard(context)
            }else{
            self.stackCard(context)
            }
        })
}


func stackCard(context: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning){
    cards--

    var plainCard = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Card"))
    plainCard.frame = container.frame

    let offScreen = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
    plainCard.alpha = 0
    plainCard.transform = offScreen
    container.addSubview(plainCard)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(transitionDuration(context), animations: {
        plainCard.alpha = 1
        plainCard.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        }, completion: {(lastOne) in if(self.cards == 0){
            self.stackLastCard(context)
        }else{
            self.stackCard(context)
        }
    })

}

func stackLastCard(context: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning){
    let offScreen = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)
    toViewController.view.alpha = 0
    toViewController.view.transform = offScreen
    container.addSubview(toViewController.view)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(transitionDuration(context), animations: {
        self.toViewController.view.alpha = 1
        self.toViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        }, completion: {(lastOne) in
        context.completeTransition(true)
        })
}
```

and then simply call startStackingCards in the animateTransition method.